# About This Computer not working on ubuntu-14.04 ARM

Tags: unity, 14.04, arm

I am using the ubuntu-14.04-core-armhf and have installed ubuntu-desktop. On the ubuntu desktop , IF I click "About This Computer" - nothing shows up. After this if I try to click "System Settings" , again nothing comes up. But when I reboot and click on "System Settings" , it works fine. Only "About This Computer" is causing issues.

On my host machine(Intel), which has Ubuntu 14.04 - "About This Computer" button works fine as intended.

Comment: Actually, "About this Computer" is the same as system Settings --> details. When I click on details, nothing happens and when I try to close the settings window, it says "This window is not responding" and asking me to wait of Force quit

Comment: After I tried to debug using strace, it seems the connection to system_bus_socket is not being made .  Comparing it with the working unity-control-center info , its Missing -- connect(13, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"}, 110)