# Dragging nautilus window over workspace switcher hang the desktop workspace GUI

Tags: 14.04, workspaces, workspace-switcher

Ubuntu 14.04 : After I enable the workspace and start moving objects/icons from one workspace to another, it works fine  for few minutes but the system freezes after sometime and I cannot do anything. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: I had this same issue with Ubuntu **14.04 LTS *beta***. *Are you fully updated?*

Comment: No , I am using the 14.04 LTS version -  $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Comment: *Does problem persist, after you have run:* **`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`**, followed by **`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`**

Comment: Seems like this issue is fixed after I update and Upgrade my host x86 machine. But same issue still exists in my target armv7 hardfp machine which is running ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The system just freezes after I drag items between workspaces. Any idea what could be the issue? Atleast any tips on where to look for debug messages or how to enable debug messages to see what's really happening ?

Comment: **To clarify:** Are you asking about *Ubuntu Touch emulator* or a *virtual machine* running 'core' Ubuntu (ARMv7)?

Comment: I download the core ubuntu 14.04 armhf from ubuntu downloads, boot onto the core rootfs,install a full-desktop using apt-get install ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: That is a **NEW** question, and you need to define / describe the target platform.

Comment: I am using nexus 7 which has 3rd generation Nvidia tegra chip. It has ARMv7 , hardfp ABI and 4 cores I guess. With respect to this issue, I guess it may be due to Ubuntu using later kernel versions but not sure

Comment: The **Nexus 7** is not currently supported as a **reference** platform, and **Ubuntu Touch** is still under development. Off subject for this forum. *Switch to **Nexus 7 (2013)** and **14.10 beta** (like I am using), or try XDA Developers.*

Comment: Well this bug isn't about the ubuntu touch. Just the ubuntu 14.04 rootfs for armhf has issues. The worskpaces on ubuntu 13.04 armhf on the nexus device wroks perfectly fine. Only with the new ubuntu 14.04 rootfs, I see this issue. Also another issue which is not seen on ubuntu 13.04 armhf but only seen on ubuntu 14.04 armhf rootfs is this -  http://askubuntu.com/questions/454798/about-this-computer-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-arm